# caffe/include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:35:23: fatal error: cublas_v2.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, caffe

I have installed caffe and opencv 2.4 on my ubuntu 14.04 machine without CUDA and GPU support. Also I have uncommented CPU_ONLY := 1 in makefile.config file.
I want to use caffe on cpu mode (on c++ platform). But I am getting error while building classification example file on codelite platform.

The error is:

> /caffe/include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:35:23: fatal error: cublas_v2.h: No such file or directory

I am not getting if I am wrong somewhere in installation or I have to make some more changes for CPU only mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2704) issue posted on the caffe github repo. The solution that worked for me was adding `add_definitions( -DCPU_ONLY=1 )` at the second line of CMakeLists.txt